# How to get resources from child's ./res/ directory in Android App

Tags: android

I have a android app folder structure like:

```
phone
├── res
└── src
└── tablet 
     ├── res
     └── src
```

Now there is an activity.java in phone/src would like to use the resources (.xml file) from phone/tablet/res, how do I access the resources from child's directory?
Thanks!

Tried `import` both `.phone.R` and `phone.tablet.R` but the latter cannot find.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your folder structure is not the one, used in Android Studio by default. I would suggest to change it to be according to default structure, because in that case Gradle can merge all the resources automatically etc., otherwise you would probably need to add some custom config in your `build.gradle`.
Below is only example with using modules/sub-modules. But maybe you need flavors instead, if you want to have separate code versions for different build types.

```
<module name> // i.e. phone
|--src
|----main
|------res
|--<sub-module name> // i.e. tablet
|----src
|------main
|--------res
|----build.gradle
|--build.gradle
```

Then in your module's `build.gradle` you add sub-module as dependency - this will allow to use sub-module's codebase from module level.

**Alternatively, if you don't need separate modules, but just want to group tablet related resources in separate folder**

```
phone
|--src
|----main
|------res
|--------tablet
```

Then in your `build.gradle` you need to specify res paths:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs = [
           'src/main/res',
           'src/main/res/tablet'
        ]
```